# Is it possible to get the parent HTML element that a script block is in?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say you have this code:

```
<div id="div1">
   <script>
      var parentNode = [code];
      console.log(parentNode); // div#div1
   </script>
</div>
```

Is there javascript that makes it possible to get the parent node that contains the script block?

How do you get a reference to the current script block and then the parent node that it is in?

Comment: Get the script node, then use `.parentElement`

Comment: @Barmar Can you show the code?

Comment: Give the script an id, then getElementById("script_id").parentElement()

Comment: Can you read the code at the linked question?

Comment: @Barmar OK I misread that close reason and the duplicate question is the same one I had. Thanks!